# How to filer key, value pair and construct rdd of keys only based on logical condition on values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val MED1_dates = medication.map{rec =>
                                val patientID = rec.patientID
                                (patientID, rec.date)
                               }

val MED1_lowest_dates = MED1_dates.reduceByKey{
  case(d1,d2) => (
    if(d1.before(d2)) d1 else d2
  )
}

val MED2_dates = medication.map{rec =>
  val patientID = rec.patientID
  (patientID, rec.date)
}

val MED2_lowest_dates = MED1_dates.reduceByKey{
  case(d1,d2) => (
    if(d1.before(d2)) d1 else d2
    )
}

val MED1_MED2_lowest_dates = MED1_lowest_dates.join(MED2_lowest_dates)
```

Now I need to filter a RDD of patientID from MED1_MED2_lowest_dates where MED2 lowest date is before MED1 lowest date. 
How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code that does what your question says. It uses a sample RDD built to demonstrate this. You can apply the similar logic to your problem.

```
val list = List((1 -> "Pune"),(2 -> "Mumbai"),(3 -> "Delhi"))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(list)
val filtered = rdd.filter{case (k,v) => (v.equals("Delhi"))}
// I HAVE USED collect as my RDD does not contain lot of data.
filtered.keys.collect
```